# Ascertaining whether a function is increasing or decreasing

Tags: calculus

In a given question I'm given the following function

$\int^{2x}_{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$

The question asks if the function is increasing or decreasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$

I've taken the integral of the function and got $\ln2$ but I'm not sure how to decipher whether the function is increasing or decreasing given this information.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the indefinite integral of $\frac{1}{t}$ is $\ln t+C$, so:
$$
f(x)=
\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t}dt=
\ln(2x)-\ln(x)=
\ln\left(\frac{2x}{x}\right)=
\ln(2)
$$ 
Therefore, $f$ is constant so it is both decreasing and increasing.

Comment: does this mean that on the interval $(0,\infty)$ the function is increasing? what do you mean when you say it is both increasing and decreasing when the integral is a constant?

Comment: @esc1234 $f$ is constant in that interval. If you examine the definition, you’ll see that a constant function is both increasing and decreasing.

Comment: i marked your answer as the answer to my original question. The key part of the answer for me was that "$f$ is constant so it is both decreasing and increasing. But I am still not sure where this information is coming from. What definition are you referring to that states if the integral of a function is a constant it is both increasing and decreasing? thanks for your feedback btw

Comment: @esc1234 you need to forget about the integral. $f$ is defined by an integral, but after evaluating we saw that it is identically equal to $\ln 2$. The definition of an increasing function: if $x<y$ in the domain, then $f(x)\le f(y)$. Here, $f\equiv\ln 2$, so for all $x, y\in (0, \infty)$ such that $x\le y$, we have $f(x)=\ln 2\le\ln 2=f(y)$ and hence $f$ is increasing there. Similarly, we obtain $f$ is decreasing there..

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{x}^{2x}{\frac{dt}{t}}=\log{2}$ therefore it is a constant function or both increasing and decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function is constant and it is always equal to $\log2$. So, it is *both* increasing and decreasing.